# Is there any ways to change the system DNS from a non admin user in C# WPF appl without running app with elevated privilege?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working on an application which involves changing the DNS of the machine based on logged in use. DNS of the logged in user should be changed based on an API response . DNS should be changed even if the logged user is a non-admin account. is there a way to change the DNS of the system without running the app with elevated privileges ?

Tried changing the DNS using "ManagementBaseObject"

```
public static void SetDNS(string DnsString)
        {
            string[] Dns = { DnsString };
            var CurrentInterface = GetActiveEthernetOrWifiNetworkInterface();
            if (CurrentInterface == null) return;

            ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
            ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
            {
                if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
                {
                    if (objMO["Caption"].ToString().Contains(CurrentInterface.Description))
                    {
                        ManagementBaseObject objdns = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                        if (objdns != null)
                        {
                            objdns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = Dns;
                            objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objdns, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code is changing the DNS but, only when the app is running with elevated privileges - i have to explicitly run the app as Admin

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [SimpleImpersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation). It is available as a nuget package also. From the project site, this is how is used:

```
var credentials = new UserCredentials(domain, username, password);
Impersonation.RunAsUser(credentials, logonType, () =>
{
    // do whatever you want as this user.
});
```

This way you can run your app as a regular user and run those code chunks that require more privileges as an admin user, as long as you provide the right credentials

I have used before and it works wonderfully.

Comment: Thanks for the Response . but in my case i have to run the app explicitly as an administrator in spite of logged in through admin user .

Comment: Have you tested? I mean, have you put your snipet inside the `//do whatever` block? and if so, do you get any exception?